# Appears an error message when closing the QMdiSubWindow

Tags: c++, qt, runtime-error, qt5

I have created a `QMainWindow` which could create one or more `QMdiSubWindow`s, and the following method is the responsible for creating the sub-windows:

```
void PSubWindow::newFile(){
  static ushort newFileCounter = 1;
  this->mdiareaContainer = this->mainWindow->findChild<QMdiArea*>("mdiArea");
  QMdiSubWindow *window = new QMdiSubWindow();
  window->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
  window->setWidget(new QPlainTextEdit);
  this->subWindow = mdiareaContainer->addSubWindow(window);
  QString FileTitle = "Untitled " + QString::number(newFileCounter++);
  this->subWindow->setWindowTitle(FileTitle);
  this->subWindow->show();
  this->mdiareaContainer->setViewMode(QMdiArea::TabbedView);
  this->mdiareaContainer->setTabsClosable(true);
  this->mdiareaContainer->setTabsMovable(true);
  this->tabs = mdiareaContainer->findChild<QTabBar*>();
  this->tabs->setExpanding(false);
  QObject::connect(this->tabs, SIGNAL(tabCloseRequested(int)), this, SLOT(on_subWindow_tabCloseRequested(int)), Qt::UniqueConnection);
}
```

As you seen in the code I have created a signal for closing which one of them.

```
void PSubWindow::on_subWindow_tabCloseRequested(int index) {
  QList<QMdiSubWindow*> sub = this->mdiareaContainer->subWindowList();
  qDebug()<< sub[index];
}
```

Always when closing the last window appear an error message during runtime, the message says:

[image]

**How can I solve that problem?**

Answer (score 1):

Check if `index` is smaller than `sub.size()`; the list will be empty because the last window has been closed, but index is probably still 0.

Comment: Is there another better way to get the sub-window which being closed before deleting it because I want to get an internal data stored in each sub-window?

Comment: Since a QMdiSubWidow is a QWidget and ultimately a QObject, you could use its destroyed() signal (so connect directly to the window, not the tab). **However**, there's no guarantee as to in what state the object is (it could be halfway deleted), so you can't query it anymore for data, position, size, etc.

Comment: Uh okay, that kinda defeats my previous comment. Recommendation is then to subclass QMdiSubWindow, catch the closeEvent() and emit your own signal so that you know the object is still intact. Then call QMdiSubWindow::closeEvent() to let it close properly.

Comment: I have tried what in your first comment and works well, but about what in your second comment, unfortunately, it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: Hmm, a bit hard to see without code. But if the first solution works... I re-read the documentation on destroyed() and the object should still be intact at that stage, including all its sub-widgets etc.

Comment: is it possible to give me an example or an external link about the correct way to use  `QMdiSubWindow::closeEvent()`? because I want to know why it doesn't work with me.

Answer (score 1):

When you remove the tab, the window is removed, so that position no longer exists in the list.

Comment: is there another better way to get the closed sub-window?

Comment: Not really, it deletes it from memory, and so it is impossible to retrieve it.